# How to remove heading styles with an inline CSS code

Tags: css

I have a question about CSS, i don't know how to remove​styles of a class with an inline CSS code.
Let me explain more,
I have a CSS file named styles.css
In this file for example my h2 has some styles, now in my article i want to use h2 but i want to remove h2's default styles(written in styles.css) for this heading.
I guess there should be a way for this case, but i don't know how?
Please tell me this css code and teach me something new.
Thanks

Edit:
Please take a look to bellow picture. As you can see this h2 has some styles, can you see the pink vertical line in right side?
Now i want to remove this h2's styles with a css code. I guess something like  my heading here should exist in CSS3. Am i right? Is there any css code for removing external css styles with an inline css code?
https://preview.ibb.co/m4BLda/Screenshot_2017_09_04_01_44_09_1.png

Here is the code:

```
h2 {
border-right: 4px solid #E20070;
font-size: 22px;
margin: 1.5em 0;
padding-right: 1em;
font-family: "Yekan",'irans',tahoma;
font-weight: normal !important;
}
```

Comment: Show us the code, please.

Comment: Take a look to picture i have uploaded now please. I'm sure you will understand what i am trying to tell.

Comment: Code not a picture. Where is your code?

Comment: I have added the CSS code of my h2.

Answer (score 2):

You said `inline`, but you should really keep your styles in a separate stylesheet file. Now, in your `styles.css` file add your own class:

```css
/* styles.css */

h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.my-other-title {
  color: red;
  border-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2>My title</h2>
<h2 class="my-other-title">My other title</h2>
```

Why does this even work? Because of [**CSS specificity**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity):

> Specificity determines, which CSS rule is applied by the browsers

Take your time learning more by reading [this article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

Comment: It will be `font-size` instead of font.

Comment: Ooops... Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Kostas for replying, yes you're right, but in this case, this h2 will be used only once and i won't use it anymore, so i guess it's better to use inline css in this situation. Also i have edited my question and i have uploaded a pic too. Could you please read added description?

Comment: I read your edit. You should inspect the `h2` element with browser's developer tools and let us know what the css code looks like. Then, we can suggest how to 'remove' it.

Comment: It looks like there is a `border-right` property, so maybe `border-right: 0` may help you (`style = "border-right: 0"`)

Comment: I have added the CSS code, and your guess is correct, it has border-right property. I will test your suggestion and sure it will work, but i want to know is there any CSS code for removing for example this h2's styles?
For example something like <h2 clear> .... </h2> 
or <h2 style="clear:style;"> ... </h2> 
or <h2 style="clear:before;"> ... </h2> 
I know none of above codes are correct, I just want to know is there something like that which i am missed or what?

Comment: You can override `h2` globally by defining an h2 style like: `h2 { border-right: 0 }` etc. in `styles.css`,  but this cannot be done inline.

Comment: ok, so you think this can not be done inline. By the way <h2 style="border-right: 0;"> My Heading </h2> works fine and remove that pink line.

Comment: But i don't know why i think there is something with a "clear" property, maybe i saw something like this somewhere in webpages !!!

Comment: Maybe you mean `unset`? It is a possible value for some properties like `width`, but not all.

Comment: There is also the [`clear` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear) but this is for floats. In your case you should override each property you need to, in your inline expression, one by one.

Comment: ok dear Kostas, i learned unset and clear properties from you, so clear property only works for floats, i will read the link you shared carefully. thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

Remove the existing class for your heading if there is and use your own custom class instead of writing everything inline.

```css
h1{
  font-size:15px;
  color:blue;
}


/* target your h1 element */
.custom-css{
  font-size:25px;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading with general css<h1>

<h1 class="custom-css">Heading with custom css</h1>
```

Although its not good to change the **semantic** of an HTML Element.

Comment: In this case i don't want to change font-size or color, i have a pink vertical line in right side of my h2 (shown in picture) and i want remove that line in just one of my headings/one of my h2(s).

Answer (score 0):

CSS - Default for `h2` (from external css source)

```
h2 {
border-right: 4px solid #E20070;
font-size: 22px;
margin: 1.5em 0;
padding-right: 1em;
font-family: "Yekan",'irans',tahoma;
font-weight: normal !important;
}
```

You want to override the default css through inline css. Try using below code for your `h2`.

```
<h2 style="border-right: 0px; padding: 0; margin: 0;"> Hello </h2>
```

You can also add a `class` to the `h2` and call the class to your stylesheet if this style is applied to most of the `h2` tags. Try to avoid inline css if possible, it may cause loading time.

Comment: Thanks for replying Bellabelle, your code is correct and it will be remove the border-right property but i was trying to find if there is a CSS code that can clear all properties of a class and after all answers here i found it seems there is no such thing in CSS.

Comment: Hi @Hamed - You only have to override those styles in CSS, I mean call another class and have the new styles for that element.

Comment: thanks again Bellabelle for the help, keep it up my friend

Answer (score -1):

```
<h2 style="color:white; font-size:80px"> My Cool Text </h2>
```

You have to write what you want to replace, for example, I changed color here.

Comment: You can remove class name instead of writing all css inline.

Comment: Thanks for replying Vignoir but this is not my case.